# Give 100s of Aws Accounts access to a resource in my account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I would like to give 100s of Aws Accounts (that I do not own) access to read and write to an S3 bucket in my account based on a IAM Role.

I would like to consider 2 directions:

- All users of the accounts would be granted access.
- Specific users from each account would be granted access.

I was looking into the trust policy limits of IAM Roles and there's a 2,048 characters limit to it, that I will probably exceed.

What is the recommended way to go about this? Could setting up federated access be an option?

Comment: Do you own these accounts? Is your goal to provide access to everyone in these accounts (that you own) or just certain principals in these accounts? If the latter, you should use Cross Account access. If you don't own these accounts, then implement federation (SSO). Also consider Cognito to issue temporary credentials. Edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: Please reread my comment. All principals (users) or just certain principals?

Comment: @JohnHanley, Question updated per your suggestions.

Comment: Federation is out. SSO is out. IAM roles cannot support hundreds of accounts in a policy. Cross Account access is based on principals so it is out. I do not know of a method to support your goal short of issuing Access Keys that you distribute to the other accounts which I do not recommend. I would rethink your objectives and design and then deploy Amazon Cognito and implement user identity based access.

Comment: @Kam What do you mean by "access to a resource in my account"? What type of resource is it (eg EC2 instance, RDS database)? How will they use it?

Comment: @JohnHanley I could change the requirements to allow specific users from each Account access to my resource, would that change things?

Comment: @JohnHanley, I have updated the question, and apologies for the confusion, I should have made my question clearer from the beginning.

Comment: Based upon your criteria (users at hundreds of AWS accounts) the only solution that I would recommend is Amazon Cognito. This will require creating an account for each user that you want to have access. Cognito will generate a temporary access token that the user can then use to securely access your S3 resources.

Comment: Make it public

#YOLO